# rails -v Get different ERRORS -

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm really frustrated two day trying to work with rails for first time but I got many errors right now when I try to get the rails version got te next:

```
  ➜  first_app $ pwd
/Users/ChrispazDev/rails_projects/first_app/first_app
➜  first_app $ rails -v
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
Rails 4.2.3
➜  first_app $ cd ..
➜  first_app $ rails -v
/Users/ChrispazDev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@update3tutorial/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/ChrispazDev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@update3tutorial/gems/rails-4.2.3/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /Users/ChrispazDev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@update3tutorial/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/ChrispazDev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@update3tutorial/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/ChrispazDev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@update3tutorial/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
➜  first_app
```

Sorry if it's something stupid but I'm really lost.

Mac OS 10.10.3
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

Regards.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by rails -v?

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails -v`. Same or different result?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the install of Rails is messed up. The last error message comes from when you were at the path `/Users/ChrisapzDev/rails_projects/first_app` compared with the original message inside a sub-directory to this path.

Additionally notice that you have RVM installed so you may need to

1. Test the path that is being used for the invocation of rails using explicit `./rails -v` to see what happens
2. Clean out the RVM Gemset  `rvm gemset empty`
3. Reinstall rails in the context of the gemset you have allocated via RVM.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of RVM, your ruby versions are messed ( Your system ruby, and ruby you installed with rvm). There is no need to uninstall RVM as it will help you to switch between your ruby versions.
Try using below code

```
rvm use system // for using system ruby
rvm use x.x.x  // Here x.x.x is version of ruby
as rvm use 2.2.2
```

May be this [tutorial](http://buffercode.in/install-rvm-ruby-and-rails/) will help you .

Comment: Thanks Neha, after several tests, started everything from zero. Now I have a clean installation. The best way I follow this [Step by Step](https://gist.github.com/tamouse/b669aacacb39b7891fc5) `Install Rails` First I did rmv implode.